# Postgresql: optimal use of multicolumn-index when subset of index is missing from the where clause

Tags: postgresql, multi-index, b-tree

I will be having queries on my database with where clauses similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 'string_value' AND b = 'other_string_value' AND t > <timestamp>
```

and less often to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 'string_value' AND t > <timestamp>
```

I have created a multicolumn index on a, b and t on that order. However I am not sure if it will be optimal for my second -less frequent- query.

Will this index do an index scan on b or skip it and move to the t index immediately? (To be honest Im not sure how index scans work exactly). Should I create a second multi-column index on a and t only for the second query?

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) state that

> 'the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns'

But in the example it doesn't highlight my case where the 'b' equality column is missing in the where clause.

Comment: have you tried doing `explain`?

Comment: Which of these conditions are selective and which are not?

Comment: @Andronicus Ohh, was not aware of explain. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe To honest I'm not familiar with the term and a quick search didn't help me. The queries are just a simple select on a table with these columns only. The combinations of the column values are unique

Comment: Which of these conditions will filter out many rows and which only a few?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Both will filter out a lot of rows. The first query will filter even more since it has an extra constraint

Comment: No. The first query has three conditions, the second two. We need to know the selectivity of each individual condition.

Comment: Well a has about 100 distinct values. b about 10 and t is the timestamp. It has 43200 values (past 30 days stored having 1 minute granularity).  Time period that we query varies but default is 60 minutes. So for first query we keep 60/(10*100*43200) and for the second 60*10/(10*100*43200) of the database (combinations are unique)

Comment: So, is your inequality sign reversed?  If queries are for the most recent hour, it would be `t > value`

Comment: @jjanes Yes you are right. I didn't think much of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd query will be much less effective with the btree index on `(a,b,t)` because the absence of `b` means `t` cannot be used efficiently (it can still be used as an in-index filter, but that is not nearly as good as being used as a start/stop point).  An index on `(a,t)` will be able to support the 2nd query much more efficiently.

But that doesn't mean you *have* to create that index as well.  Indexes take space and must be maintained, so are far from free.  It might be better to just live with less-than-optimal plans for the 2nd query, since that query is used "less often".  On the other hand, you did bother to post about it, so maybe "less often" is still pretty often.  So you might be better off just to build the extra index and spend your time worrying about something else.

A btree index can be thought of like a phonebook, which is sorted on last name, then first name, then middle name.  Your first query is like searching for "people named Mary Smith with a middle name less than Cathy" You can use binary search to efficiently find the first "Mary Smith", then you scan through those until the middle name is > 'Cathy', and you are done.  Compare that to "people surnamed Smith with a middle name less than Cathy".  Now you have to scan all the Smith's.  You can't stop at the first middle name > Cathy, because any change in first name resets the order of the middle names.

Given that `b` only has 10 distinct values, you could conceivably use the `(a,b,t)` index in a skip scan quite efficiently.  But PostgreSQL doen't yet implement skip scans natively.  You can emulate them, but that is fragile, ugly, a lot of work, and easy to screw up.  Nothing you said here makes me think it would be worthwhile to do.

Comment: And if I define an index (a, t, b)/(last_name, middle, first) and find the Smiths and then all Smiths that middle name > 'Cathy', what stops me from using the first_name index efficiently to find the Marys? Maybe beause using this 'first_name ' index will point me to Marys outside of the 'Smiths with middle>'Cathy''  selection and hecne a scan of the this index is required?

Comment: There is no first name index.  There is (hypothetically) just one index on all three columns simultaneously.  You would have to read all entries with qualifying last and middle names, and manually inspect and throw out the ones not named Mary.  This might not be a bad approach, but it would be less good than the optimal on (by about 10x) for the query that you will run most often; so I didn't mention it as I figured you would not be willing to take that loss on the most-used query.